# Ruby on Rails - parameter gives nil result back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, parameters

parameter

```
"day" => "2013-11-21"
```

controller

```
date = params[:day] # gives me a nil value back
@event = Event.new(date: date, id: date.id)
```

view

```
...
<% f.hidden_field :id, :value => :day %>
...
```

Here are the parameters:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"lxKzvpGx8nmutI8X8sdZGNaKZ8w1kJEdF/B8ixtqpqA=",
 "event"=>{"title"=>"",
 "description"=>"",
 "day"=>"2013-11-21",
 "start(1i)"=>"2013",
 "start(2i)"=>"11",
 "start(3i)"=>"22",
 "start(4i)"=>"08",
 "start(5i)"=>"00",
 "end(1i)"=>"2013",
 "end(2i)"=>"11",
 "end(3i)"=>"22",
 "end(4i)"=>"08",
 "end(5i)"=>"00"},
 "commit"=>"Create Event"}
```

why gives it to me a nil value back?

let me know if you need something more

Comment: How do you set this parameter?

Comment: in the view: `<% f.hidden_field :id, :value => :day %>`

Comment: @ciaodarwin can you post your full params list from console?

Comment: because params `:day` included into `event`. You should `params[:event][:day]`. It is obviously after suggestion to post params - say thanks to @user2675613

Comment: You need to use `params[:event][:day]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `params[:event][:day]` instead of `params[:day]`

Comment: @ciaodarwin Aha its alright! It happens that's why they are called silly mistakes :D

Answer (score 1):

I see at least three problems.

1. Your param is accessible through `params[:event][:day]`, as you should see in the parameters list you posted.
2. The hidden field you posted doesn't set `params[:event][:day]` parameter. Actually, it does nothing as it isn't even being rendered (because of `<%` usage, instead of `<%=`.
3. You try to misuse this parameter, calling `id` on it (in `@event = Event.new(date: date, id: date.id)` line). Even if you refer to that parameter properly, it will raise an error.